# Data conversion error converting "'1TRUE'

Tags: h2

I'm trying to run the following query:
Preparing:

```
INSERT INTO manual_sentences (project_id, sentence_id, weight, is_from_external_source, original_sentence_id, `partition`) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + ?, is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source || ?
```

Parameters: `42(Long), 1316(Long), 1(Integer), true(Boolean), 1315(Long), 0(Integer), 1(Integer), true(Boolean)`

If `is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source || ?` kicks in, the following error is returned on H2 DB running on MySQL mode:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: 
### Error updating database.  Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "'1TRUE' (MANUAL_SENTENCES: IS_FROM_EXTERNAL_SOURCE TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO manual_sentences (project_id, sentence_id, weight, is_from_external_source, original_sentence_id, `partition`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + ?, is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source || ? [22018-175]
### The error may involve com.nuance.entrd.mc.nes.persistence.mappers.IManualSentenceMapper.addManualSentenceObject-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: INSERT INTO manual_sentences (project_id, sentence_id, weight, is_from_external_source, original_sentence_id, `partition`)         VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + ?, is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source || ?
### Cause: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "'1TRUE' (MANUAL_SENTENCES: IS_FROM_EXTERNAL_SOURCE TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO manual_sentences (project_id, sentence_id, weight, is_from_external_source, original_sentence_id, `partition`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + ?, is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source || ? [22018-175]
; SQL []; Data conversion error converting "'1TRUE' (MANUAL_SENTENCES: IS_FROM_EXTERNAL_SOURCE TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO manual_sentences (project_id, sentence_id, weight, is_from_external_source, original_sentence_id, `partition`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + ?, is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source || ? [22018-175]; nested exception is org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Data conversion error converting "'1TRUE' (MANUAL_SENTENCES: IS_FROM_EXTERNAL_SOURCE TINYINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL)"; SQL statement:
INSERT INTO manual_sentences (project_id, sentence_id, weight, is_from_external_source, original_sentence_id, `partition`) 
        VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE weight = weight + ?, is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source || ? [22018-175]
```

Any idea on how I can overcome this besides passing integer instead of boolean values?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use

```
is_from_external_source = is_from_external_source or ?
```

instead. I think it is more logical to use `or` for boolean "or" instead of `||`, because `||` is the concatenation operation.

This question is a duplicate of [H2 issue 553](https://code.google.com/p/h2database/issues/detail?id=553).